# Установка Ubuntu рядом с Windows

Tags: windows, ubuntu, установка, dual-boot

Подскажите, как поставить Ubuntu второй ОС на компьютер?

Answer (score 3):

Вот тут есть подробная инструкция как это сделать: [Установка Ubuntu](http://pingvinus.ru/note/ubuntu-install)